# How do I check if a string is contained in another string?

Tags: c, substring, string-comparison

Example in python:

```
>>> a="Sweet potato"
>>> "potato" in a
True
```

I thought it might be `strcmp`, but `strcmp` must be identical match, no?

Comment: C has [many string functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte), you might want to explore them.

Comment: `if (strstr(str, "potato")) puts("True");`

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=c+search+for+substring

Comment: The **very first Google hit ^^ above** is the appropriate SO question/answer.

Comment: sub string wont appear on my head >< Oh well. Let's not make another mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` is used to determined if two string are identical.

if you want to find if a string contain a sub string there are severel way. a very good one is what  Alter Mann wrote:

```
if (strstr(str, "potato")) puts("True");
```

Comment: I would go for `return strstr(str,"potato") != NULL`, but in either case, this answer does **not** deserve a down-vote.